# Stylus CSS highlighting plugin for Netbeans?

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, stylus

Stylus CSS pre-processor is awesome but since i used to code in Netbeans, it is hard to code without color highlighting. is there any Netbeans plugin for Stylus available? If any, it'll be perfect!

Thanks

Comment: Even i want answer for this. If anybody knows please share the link

Comment: it seems no one know about this. so i just use WebStorm from JetBrains. it's a great web IDE like netbeans. it comes with default highlighting feature for variety of files i needed. and it supports transpiling Stylus to CSS directly.

Answer (score 5):

[Does this help?](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/netbeans-syntax-highlighting-file-extensions/) This says how to make syntax highlighting based on file extension?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I gave up with Netbeans. Just purchase WebStorm version 9 or above from JetBrains [Jet Brains Site here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) It comes with Stylus Highlighting, smart completion assistance and even Stylus-to-CSS converstion on the fly. If you're PHP developer you can use PHPStorm from same developer

[image: JetBrains WebStorm]